Seahorse not showing passwords tab after Ubuntu 24.04 update
I use Seahorse with Ubuntu to store passwords. I just updated from Ubuntu 20somethingLTS to 24.04LTS. When I open Seahorse now (v.43), I see only GnuPG Keys and OpenSSH Keys in the lefthand menu. There is no "Passwords" option there anymore. I looked in .local/share/keyrings and found login.keyring, which I believe to be the file containing my passwords. Is there a way to get Seahorse to "see" that file? I'm not a very advanced user, so beginner-oriented advice is appreciated, thank you!

This answer didn't work for me, but one comment underneath it mentioned entering sudo apt-get install dbus-user-session && systemctl --user start dbus.service and I tried that, restarted my computer, and now I have the correct "login" menu item, and my passwords are there.
